# Jenkins app is not accessible outside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

On `CentOS 7.4`, I have set up a Kubernetes master node, pulled down jenkins image and deployed it to the cluster defining the jenkins service on a NodePort as below.

I can curl the jenkins app from the worker or master nodes using the IP defined by the service. But, I can not access the Jenkins app (dashboard) from my browser (outside cluster) using the public IP of the master node.

```
[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
abcdefgh   Ready    master   19h   v1.13.1
hgfedcba   Ready    <none>   19h   v1.13.1

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ sudo docker pull jenkinsci/jenkins:2.154-alpine

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                v1.13.1             fdb321fd30a0        5 days ago          80.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.13.1             26e6f1db2a52        5 days ago          146MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver            v1.13.1             40a63db91ef8        5 days ago          181MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler            v1.13.1             ab81d7360408        5 days ago          79.6MB
jenkinsci/jenkins                    2.154-alpine        aa25058d8320        2 weeks ago         222MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns                   1.2.6               f59dcacceff4        6 weeks ago         40MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                      3.2.24              3cab8e1b9802        2 months ago        220MB
quay.io/coreos/flannel               v0.10.0-amd64       f0fad859c909        10 months ago       44.6MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        12 months ago       742kB

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw------- 1 administrator administrator 678 Dec 18 06:12 jenkins-deployment.yaml
-rw------- 1 administrator administrator 410 Dec 18 06:11 jenkins-service.yaml

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ cat jenkins-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: ui
  selector:
    app: jenkins-master
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-discovery
spec:
  selector:
    app: jenkins-master
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
      name: jenkins-slaves

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ cat jenkins-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: jenkins/jenkins:2.154-alpine
          name: jenkins
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http-port
            - containerPort: 50000
              name: jnlp-port
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl create -f jenkins-service.yaml
service/jenkins-ui created
service/jenkins-discovery created

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl get services
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
jenkins-discovery   ClusterIP   10.98.--.--     <none>        50000/TCP        19h
jenkins-ui          NodePort    10.97.--.--     <none>        8080:31587/TCP   19h
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.--.--     <none>        443/TCP          20h

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl create -f jenkins-deployment.yaml
deployment.extensions/jenkins created

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl get deployments
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
jenkins   1/1     1            1           19h

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       jenkins-6497cf9dd4-f9r5b               1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-jfq5b               1/1     Running   0          20h
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-s4k6d               1/1     Running   0          20h
kube-system   etcd-abcdefgh                          1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-abcdefgh                1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-abcdefgh       1/1     Running   5          20h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-2w68w            1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-6zl4g            1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-proxy-9r4xt                       1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-proxy-s7fj2                       1/1     Running   1          20h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-abcdefgh                1/1     Running   8          20h

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl describe pod jenkins-6497cf9dd4-f9r5b
Name:               jenkins-6497cf9dd4-f9r5b
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               hgfedcba/10.41.--.--
Start Time:         Tue, 18 Dec 2018 06:32:50 -0800
Labels:             app=jenkins-master
                    pod-template-hash=6497cf9dd4
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.--.--
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/jenkins-6497cf9dd4
Containers:
  jenkins:
    Container ID:   docker://55912512a7aa1f782784690b558d74001157f242a164288577a85901ecb5d152
    Image:          jenkins/jenkins:2.154-alpine
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:b222875a2b788f474db08f5f23f63369b0f94ed7754b8b32ac54b8b4d01a5847
    Ports:          8080/TCP, 50000/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 18 Dec 2018 07:16:32 -0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      JAVA_OPTS:  -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
    Mounts:
      /var/jenkins_home from jenkins-home (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wqph5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  jenkins-home:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  default-token-wqph5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wqph5
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl describe svc jenkins-ui
Name:                     jenkins-ui
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=jenkins-master
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.97.--.--
Port:                     ui  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 ui  31587/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.--.--:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

# Check if NodePort along with Kubernetes ports are open
[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ sudo su root
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# systemctl start firewalld
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6443/tcp        # Kubernetes API Server
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 6443:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2379-2380/tcp   # etcd server client API
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 2379-2380:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10250/tcp       # Kubelet API
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 10250:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10251/tcp       # kube-scheduler
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 10251:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10252/tcp       # kube-controller-manager
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 10252:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10255/tcp       # Read-Only Kubelet API
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 10255:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=31587/tcp       # NodePort of jenkins-ui service
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 31587:tcp
success
[root@abcdefgh administrator]# firewall-cmd --reload
success

[administrator@abcdefgh ~]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.41.--.--:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.41.--.--:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

[administrator@hgfedcba ~]$ curl 10.41.--.--:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.41.--.--:8080; Connection refused

# Successfully curl jenkins app using its service IP from the worker node
[administrator@hgfedcba ~]$ curl 10.97.--.--:8080

  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/5882d14a" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/5882d14a">
    <title>Dashboard [Jenkins]</title><link rel="stylesheet" ...
    ...
```

Would you know how to do that? Happy to provide additional logs. Also, I have installed jenkins from yum on another similar machine without any docker or kubernetes and it's possible to access it through 10.20.30.40:8080 in my browser so there is no provider firewall preventing me from doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jenkins Service is of type `NodePort`. That means that a specific port number, on any node within your cluster, will deliver your Jenkins UI.

When you described your Service, you can see that the port assigned was `31587`.

You should be able to browse to `http://SOME_IP:31587`